# DataTables Not Showing Up-To-Date Rows

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have the following bit of code that is being displayed in a bootstrap modal (if that's relevant):

```
$(document).on('click', '.queued_auto_responders', function (event) {
    if (table_queued_responders !== null) {
        table_queued_responders.destroy();
    }
    // queued_ids from the clicked row
    var customer_id = $(this).attr('data-customer-id');
    $.ajax({
        "type": "GET",
        "url": "assets/php/get_automatic_responder.php",
        "data": {"customer_id": customer_id},
        "dataType": "json"
    }).done(function(queued_emails) {
        table_queued_responders = $('#queued_auto_responders').DataTable({
            "data": queued_emails,
            "columns": [
                { data: "queue_id", visible: false },
                { data: "send_date", title: 'Send Date' },
                { data: "title", title: "Title" },
                { data: "approved", visible: false },
                { data: "already_sent", visible: false },
                { data: null, title: 'Action', createdCell:
                function (td, cellData, rowData, row, col) {
                    var button = $("<button />",
                        {
                            "class": "btn btn-outline-danger btn-block stop-queued-responder",
                            "text": "Stop Email",
                            "type": "button"
                        }).attr("data-queue-id", rowData.queue_id);

                        if (rowData.approved == 1 && rowData.already_sent == 0) {
                            $(td).html(button.prop("outerHTML"));
                        } else {
                            $(td).html("");
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        });
    }).always(function() {
        table_queued_responders.draw();
    });
    $('#queued_auto_responders').closest('.table-responsive').css('display', '');
});
```

What is odd is that this code does indeed work, but only some of the time. Some of the time it will display the data without any problems, but other times it will not display the data and instead it will display: *"No Matching Records Found."* in the body and then *"Showing 0 to 0 of 0 entries (filtered from n total entries)"* where n is the number of records returned.

If I inspect my network tab, I confirmed that there is data being returned every time.

Also, what happens is if I click on the DOM element that has the `.queued_auto_responders` it reopens the modal and it has the old data from the previous DOM element for a brief moment before it shows the message again.

**UPDATE**

As per Bilal Ahmed's suggestion, I've also tried initializing the table once (instead of calling destroy), removing the existing rows, and then adding the new ones:

```
// upcoming auto-responder button click
var table_queued_responders = table_queued_responders = $('#queued_auto_responders').DataTable({
    "columns": [
        { data: "queue_id", visible: false },
        { data: "send_date", title: 'Send Date' },
        { data: "title", title: "Title" },
        { data: "approved", visible: false },
        { data: "already_sent", visible: false },
        { data: null, title: 'Action', createdCell:
        function (td, cellData, rowData, row, col) {
            var button = $("<button />",
                {
                    "class": "btn btn-outline-danger btn-block stop-queued-responder",
                    "text": "Stop Email",
                    "type": "button"
                }).attr("data-queue-id", rowData.queue_id);

            if (rowData.approved == 1 && rowData.already_sent == 0) {
                $(td).html(button.prop("outerHTML"));
            } else {
                $(td).html("");
            }
        }
        }
    ]
});
$(document).on('click', '.queued_auto_responders', function (event) {
    table_queued_responders.rows().remove().draw();
    // queued_ids from the clicked row
    var customer_id = $(this).attr('data-customer-id');
    $.ajax({
        "type": "GET",
        "url": "assets/php/get_automatic_responder.php",
        "data": {"customer_id": customer_id},
        "dataType": "json"
    }).done(function(n) {
        table_queued_responders.rows.add(n).draw();
    });
    $('#queued_auto_responders').closest('.table-responsive').css('display', '');
});
```

The same behavior happens, with the exception of the old data showing, now even that isn't happening.

**Update 2**

I was able to get it to work by literally looping through the response from the AJAX call and manually adding rows one by one. I have no idea why it doesn't work when calling `rows.add` but it works with `row.add`.

Comment: Assuming there is no error in console. Place the `debugger;` & `console.log(data);` techniques where you feel the data is being lost. Also, try reproducing the same issue in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) as the issue is still unclear!

Comment: @BilalAhmed I don't want for this to sound rude, but I have setup `console.log`s and `debuggers`, this is why I've resorted to asking my question on SO. The output of `queued_emails` is exactly what is being returned from the endpoint, which is why I'm thinking this is something to do with the datatables plugin.

Comment: You don't need to initialize `.DataTable()` every single time you click `.queued_auto_responders`. Rather, initialize `DataTable()` right after `$(document).ready();` into a variable and simply just add rows into that variable returned from the back-end, this way : `table_queued_responders .rows.add(queued_emails).draw();`. Initializing the same `DataTable()` multiple times should generate error!

Comment: @BilalAhmed I'm actually calling `Destroy` at the top of the event handler to prevent it from erroring, but I will try your suggestion whenever I get home.

Comment: @BilalAhmed - see my update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove extra `table_queued_responders =` while `DataTable()` initialization.

```
// upcoming auto-responder button click
var table_queued_responders = $('#queued_auto_responders').DataTable({
    "columns": [
        { data: "queue_id", visible: false },
        { data: "send_date", title: 'Send Date' },
        { data: "title", title: "Title" },
        { data: "approved", visible: false },
        { data: "already_sent", visible: false },
        { data: null, title: 'Action',
    createdCell: function (td, cellData, rowData, row, col) {
            var button = $("<button />",
                {
                    "class": "btn btn-outline-danger btn-block stop-queued-responder",
                    "text": "Stop Email",
                    "type": "button"
                }).attr("data-queue-id", rowData.queue_id);

            if (rowData.approved == 1 && rowData.already_sent == 0) {
                $(td).html(button.prop("outerHTML"));
            } else {
                $(td).html("");
            }
        }
        }
    ]
});
```

Plus, change your `click()` event to the below code :

```
$(document).on('click', '.queued_auto_responders', function (event) {
// queued_ids from the clicked row
var customer_id = $(this).attr('data-customer-id');
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'assets/php/get_automatic_responder.php',
    data: {'customer_id': customer_id},
    success : function(data){
        table_queued_responders.rows().remove().draw();
        if (data.length > 0) {
           table_queued_responders.rows.add(data).draw();
        }
      }
    });
    //$('#queued_auto_responders').closest('.table-responsive').css('display', '');
});
```

the above code is how I request for data and populate it into the datatables. A slight change is that I replaced the `.done()` event with the `.success()` and removing the prior data right after the `.success()` is achieved. This code is working on my side. Try it and do let me know!

Comment: Thank you for this, I ultimately wound up using this but I did change back to done because success was deprecated some while back. Also, I had to specify the dataType of the AJAX request to JSON. Other than that everything works perfectly.